# "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement functools (from versions: 0.5)"

Tags: python, pip, functools

I'm trying to install functools module in python with: pip install functools

but i encounter this error:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement functools (from versions: 0.5)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for functools

Comment: functools is builtin in Python. Can you check if import functools works for you?

Answer (score 1):

functools is part of the basic Python installation (you cannot install it separately).  If `import functools` doesn't work in your Python scripts, you should consider reinstalling Python itself.